# W/System.err(1570): Starting the internal HTTP client in android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, restlet, google-cloud-datastore

I am **uploading some data to Google cloud datastore using restlet framework from android application** , I have create d a google web application and it is running in localhost  http://localhost:8888/data , While I am accessing it from my testing device I have changed my localhost to 
http://10.0.2.2:8888/data , I have added **restlet 2.3.4 for android** ,while I am running my app I am getting the following error giving my logcat below , a **system error** : I have added **internet permission** in manifest file , can anybody help me out here... the same url is working fine for java application.

my asynctask

```
private class UploadToCloud extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        ClientResource cr = new ClientResource("http://10.0.2.2:8888/timerdata");
        Gson g = new Gson();
        ArrayList<DataModel> deviceData = new ArrayList<DataModel>();

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

        cr.setRequestEntityBuffering(true);
        cr.addQueryParameter("userId", "DD");

         Random random = new Random();

          int tHr = showRandomInteger(25, 40, random);
          int tMin = showRandomInteger(1, 60, random);
          int tSec = showRandomInteger(1, 60, random);

            DataModel btc =new DataModel();
            btc.setTimerHr(tHr);
            btc.setTimerMin(tMin);
            btc.setTimerSec(tSec);

            deviceData.add(btc);
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String...urls) {

            try 
            {
                StringRepresentation stringRep = new StringRepresentation(g.toJson(deviceData));
                stringRep.setMediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

                System.out.println(stringRep.getText());

                Representation res= cr.put(stringRep);


                System.out.println(cr.getResponse());

            } 
            catch (ResourceException e)
            {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String message) {

        }
    }
```

logcat

```
  08-27 17:20:59.571: I/System.out(1570): [{"timerHr":32,"timerMin":44,"timerSec":55,"userId":207}]
    08-27 17:20:59.636: W/System.err(1570): Starting the internal HTTP client
    08-27 17:20:59.646: I/System.out(1570): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
    08-27 17:20:59.646: I/System.out(1570): (HTTPLog)-Static: isShipBuild true
    08-27 17:20:59.646: I/System.out(1570): (HTTPLog)-Thread-15475-256028228: SmartBonding Enabling is false, SHIP_BUILD is true, log to file is false, DBG is false
    08-27 17:20:59.646: I/System.out(1570): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
    08-27 17:20:59.651: I/System.out(1570): KnoxVpnUidStorageknoxVpnSupported API value returned is false
```

Comment: unrelated to appengine. removed tag

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to make a network request on the MainThread. Use AsycTask to do that.